# Find and replace string in all files and folders in a certain directory

Tags: linux

I have SSH access to a web hosting server. There are several thousand files, most of which contain the string 'Copyright ABC'.

I would like to change the string in the (and all files in the sub-folders) code of all of these files to 'Copyright XYZ' as our company has acquired the old site and we must change the footer.

Comment: Have you attempted anything?

Comment: Have you looked at `sed -i` (`sed -i.bak` to save the original files with a `.bak` extension). The form would be similar to `sed -i 's/Copyright[ ]ABC/Copyright[ ]XYZ/' filename`? (you can call `sed` from `find` if globbing is insufficient.)

Answer (score 1):

Use `find` to get your files, then `xargs` to use them  with `sed`

```
find /your/path -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's!Copyright ABC!Copyright XYZ!g'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/Copyright ABC/Copyright XYZ/g' {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

I like perl pie!

```
 find /your/path/ -type f -exec perl -p -i -e's/Copyright ABC/Copyright XYZ/g' {} \;
```